# NIO delete dirs and file

Tags: java

trying NIO and got two problems.1)
create dir files and two inner dirs with file in last dir.

```
Path pathDir = Path.of("files", "firstDir", "secondDir");
Path pathFile = Path.of("files", "firstDir", "secondDir", "file.txt");
    
Files.createDirectories(pathDir);
Files.createFile(pathFile);
```

is there any way to combine this into one expression so as not to create folders and files separately?
2) deleting file with dirs

```
Files.deleteIfExists(pathFile); //delete only file
Files.deleteIfExists(pathDir); // delete only last dir secondDir
```

deletes one item at a time, how to delete all folders and a file at once?

I found such an example, but it also deletes only the file

```
 Files.walk(pathFile)
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .forEach(File::delete);
```

and this option deletes only one file

```
try {
    Files.walkFileTree(pathFile, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("delete file: " + file.toString());
            Files.delete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(dir);
            System.out.println("delete dir: " + dir.toString());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete directory and file from the root path use the following method:

```
public static void deleteFilesAndDir(Path pathDir) throws IOException {
        Files.walk(pathDir)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .forEach(fileToDelete -> {
                    if (!Files.isDirectory(fileToDelete)) {
                        try {
                            Files.delete(fileToDelete);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (fileToDelete.toFile().getParentFile().length() == 0) {
                            try {
                                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(fileToDelete.toFile().getParent()));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public static boolean deleteDirectory(File directoryToBeDeleted) {
        File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
        if (allContents != null) {
            for (File file : allContents) {
                deleteDirectory(file);
            }
        }
        return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
    }
```

Call the above method like below:

```
deleteDirectory(Path.of("files"))
```

Comment: thanks man ... by calling `deleteDirectory(Path.of("files").toFile());  `

Comment: This solution doesn't answer to the first question and uses an external library not necessary

Answer (score 1):

1. To create folders and a file you can use this:

```
        Path myRoot = Paths.get("files");
        Path pathDir = myRoot
                .resolve("firstDir")
                .resolve("secondDir");
        final boolean created = Files.createDirectories(pathDir)
                .resolve("file.txt")
                .toFile()
                .createNewFile();
```

2. To delete a folder recursively you must start walking from the folder itself

```java
         Files.walk(Paths.get("files"))
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .forEach(File::delete);
```

Comment: delites file and secondDir . files/firstDir stays

Comment: the same thing delites file and secondDir . files/firstDir stays

Comment: @стасевич please make sure to start the walk from the "files" Path, in my example is the myRoot variable. I checked the code and it works

Comment: thanks... thats was a problem. need to path root folder

Comment: @стасевич I think you marked as accepted the wrong answer